# How to pass state using Link to parent route and How to access it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have tried to pass state data using Link and i already read some article with this problem but it doesnt work on my code. and i'm still learning about react and i make this project for personal

i using "this.props.location.state" in parent route but it undefined. can you hel me find the solution with this problem.

//this My Apps (Main)

```html
<Router>
  <div className="App">
     <Navbar userData={this.state.userData}/>
        <div>
           <Switch>
             <Route exact path={'/'} component={home}/>
             <Route path={'/Profile'} component={profile}/>
             <Route path={'/Explore'} component={explore}/>
           </Switch>
       </div>
    </div>
 </Router>
```

//this in Navbar component and i'm using Link

```html
 <Link
     to={{
        pathname: "/Profile",
        state: { userId: this.state.userId }
        }}
  >
     <img alt=" " src={profile}/>
</Link>
```

when i console.log(this.props.location.state) at Apps is always undefined, and i have try this Link pass data concept in "profile" and have a same result

can you give an explanation about this problem. Thank you

Comment: you will get that state value in `Profile` router

Answer (score 0):

you can't pass `state` with `<Link />`.

```
// In Route
 <Route path='/profile/:userId' component={Profile} />

// Profile.js
     <Link to={`/Profile/${this.state.userId}`}>
         <img alt=" " src={profile}/>
    </Link>
And read in 
  let userId = parseInt(props.match.params.userId, 10);
```

Check this https://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html

Comment: It is have same problem?, now i'm using Link from 'react-router-dom';

Comment: @nickomarsellino just added one link for your reference

Comment: thank you, how i get the parameter of `/Profile/${this.state.userId}` , thank you

Comment: @nickomarsellino it will be nice if you upvote this answer since it is an accepted one.